# Recreate binary search tree BST

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a Binary Search Tree and each of its node has two values.

```
int value;
String name;
```

So its node is like this.

```
class Node {
        int value;
        String name;
        Node left, right;
}
```

I have inserted values in BST according to the ascending order of "name" variable of node. So inorder traversal of tree will return the nodes in ascending order of "name".

Now I want to create a new BST from this BST whose nodes will be sorted according to "value" variable. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: If `name` is entirely independent of `value`, then it seems the only option is to just rebuild the BST, but based on `value` instead of `name`. I don't think there's a more efficient way to do that.

Comment: If there is no relation between `name` and `value` then you have to rebuild the tree.